# Error: Route.post() requires a callback function but got a [object Undefined] throw new Error(msg);

Tags: node.js, mongodb

when I try to run the server, I get Route.get() requires callback functions but got a [object Undefined] error. If I comment out the router.post('/signup',validateRequest,isRequestValidated,signup)
everything works okay.

does anyone know what the problem might be and how to fix it?

**router file:**

```
const express = require('express');
const { signup, signin } = require('../controller/auth')
const {validateRequest,isRequestValidated} =require('../validators/auth')
const router = express.Router();





router.get('/signin', signin)
router.post('/signup',validateRequest,isRequestValidated,signup)

//Auth Guard
// router.post('/profile', requireSignin, (req, res) => {
//     res.status(200).json({ user: 'profile' })
// })


module.exports = router;
```

**validator file:**

```
const { check, validationResult } = require('express-validator')
exports.validateSignUpRequest = [
    check('firstName')
        .notEmpty()
        .withMessage('First Name is Required..!'),
    check('lastName')
        .notEmpty()
        .withMessage('Last Name is Required..!'),
    check('email')
        .isEmail()
        .withMessage('Plz Enter a Valid Email Address..'),
    check('password')
        .isLength({ min: 6 })
        .withMessage('Password must be more than 6 characters')
];

exports.isRequestValidated = (req, res, next) => {
    const errors = validationResult(req)
    if (errors.array().length > 0) {
        return res.status(400).json({ errors: errors.array()[0].msg })
    }
    next()
};
```

**controller file :**

```
const User = require('../models/user');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const env = require('dotenv')
env.config()
// const {validationResult} = require('express-validator')
 //SIGNUP: 

exports.signup = (req, res) => {
    

    User.findOne({ email: req.body.email })
        .then((user) => {
            if (user) {
                res.status(400).json('User already exists')
            }
            else {
                const _user = new User({
                    firstName: req.body.firstName,
                    lastName: req.body.lastName,
                    email: req.body.email,
                    password: req.body.password,
                    username: Math.random().toString()
                })
                _user.save()
                res.status(200).json(_user)
            }
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            res.status(500).json("Something Went Wrong")
        })
}
```

Comment: This error means that your router files is not reading the value of signup,it's getting as undefined as if you did not export it

Answer (score 1):

change:

```
const {validateRequest,isRequestValidated} =require('../validators/auth')
```

to:

```
const {validateSignUpRequest,isRequestValidated} =require('../validators/auth')
```

and change:

```
router.post('/signup',validateRequest,isRequestValidated,signup)
```

to:

```
router.post('/signup',validateSignUpRequest,isRequestValidated,signup)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, the problem is solved